# Как кешировать страницы в Django?

Tags: python, django, кэширование

Читал, что с помощью кеширования можно добиться значительного ускорения генерации страницы, экономя при этом ресурсы сервера. win-win, как не поверни. Достаточно ли будет навесить на `view` [нужный декоратор](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache), описанный в документации, чтобы все было круто?

Comment: Хорошая статья, молодец

Answer (score 7):

Достаточно для полностью статических страниц. Совсем недостаточно и вредно (приводит к ошибкам, далеко не всегда очевидным) для страниц динамических.

---

Предположим, что у нас есть некая страница, требующая кеширования. Она не статична, присутствуют элементы, наличие и вид которых зависит от конкретного пользователя и его прав. Самый простой пример - шапка сайта, где написано `Привет, {{ username  }}`. Также есть элементы, общие для всех пользователей. Сам шаблон выглядит как-то так:

```
{% include header.html %}

{% for elem in elements %}
    <p>{{ elem.text }}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% if user.has_rights %}
    <button>Add new!</button>
{% endfor %}
```

где `elements = Elements.objects.filter(display=True).all()`, то есть список элементов общий, но кнопка только для администраторов.

Еще пример - магазин, где список товаров - общий, а корзина различна для всех.

Django из коробки предоставляет несколько способов закешировать данные:

- [Глобально для всех запросов](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache): нужно включить `UpdateCacheMiddleware` и `FetchFromCacheMiddleware`:

  ```
  MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
      'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
       # ... Другие слои ...
      'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware'
  )
  ```

  Глобально - значит пользователь ВАСЯ залогинившись закеширует данные, специфичные для своего пользователя (например, приветствие `"Привет, Вася!"`) и все пользователи, пришедшие после Васи получат его приветствие вместо своего. И все минуты или часы до протухания они будут видеть себя как Васю, и у них не будет никакой возможности отменить или избегать такого поведения. Это будет печальное поведение, путающее пользователей. Пригодно, если у нас пара статичных страниц и ни пользователей, ни динамического контента нет. Но тогда зачем Django?
- [Индивидуально под каждую вьюху](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache): `@cache_page(<время в секундах>)` Страдает от тех же самых проблем, но хотя бы можно поставить период обновления индивидуально. TTL (Time to live) не сделает этот инструмент волшебным, но подойдет для каких-то редких страниц без шапки с приветствием.
- [Закешировать что-нибудь в шаблоне](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching), используя директиву `{% cache %}`. Уже много лучше - можно отдельно закешировать шапку с приветствием для каждого пользователя отдельно, а для анонимов отдельно + общие данные отдельно. Однако, в этом случае страдает скорость генерации страницы, потому что процесс загрузки шаблона и его отрисовки крайне неспешный и выгоды в скорости не так высоки, как может ожидаться. Также не факт, что другие шаблонизаторы поддерживают такой функционал. Также тот факт, что мы закешировали конечный результат (HTML разметку) не отменяет необходимости обратиться к БД во вьюхе и обращаться мы тогда будем совершенно зря, потому что результаты не будут использованы. Однако, такое решение тоже имеет право существовать - генерация HTML на основе шаблонов не самая быстрая операция, а в сжатом виде занимает считанные мегабайты на тысячи страниц. Если отойти от производительности, то с точки зрения архитектуры у кеша внутри шаблонов также не все гладко. Нужно, например, внимательно помнить обо всех условиях отображения, обо всех условиях во вьюхе и в шаблоне, что в долгосрочной перспективе с несколькими разработчиками и кучей абстракций в течение лет может затруднить разработку и хуже того - чревато трудноуловимы ошибками, связанных с кешированием частей, специфичных для какой-то одной группы пользователей. Например, мы не учитываем статус суперпользвателя. Вася-админ запросил страницу первым после момента ее протухания - и вот уже в кеше страница с админскими кнопками. Или чаще наоборот - админ-Вася потеряет все свои кнопки, потому что в кеше страница для анонима.
- [Кеширование на уровне моделей](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-cacheops), предоставляемое несколькими сторонними приложениями. Кажется, что это и есть серебряная пуля, но на деле у такого подхода множество ограничений и самое главное ограничение - все механизмы скрыты от программиста и подключив эту штуку в уже существующий проект будет сложно ответить сломается ли что-нибудь или нет. С такими страхами невозможно будет использовать основную фичу подобного подхода (кеширование без TTL с обновлением по событиям CRUD). Если бы кеширующая библиотека предоставляла гарантии того, что как бы не изголялись, то данные в кеше никогда не протухнут - это было бы лучшее решение. Единственное решение, которое явно пишет о гарантиях (и поддерживает старую жангу 1.6+) и внушает этим доверие - [django-cachalot](http://django-cachalot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html), однако, мне неизвестно, выполняются ли это гарантии на практике в краткосрочной и долгосрочной перспективе. Даже если так, то всплывают другие ограничения - например, [необходимость синхронизации часов нескольких серверов](http://django-cachalot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/limits.html#multiple-servers-clock-synchronisation) или репликаций.
- Забыть про все это, положившись на внутренне кеширование Django внутри `QuerySet`. Тоже могло бы быть каким-то временным выходом, однако, в этом случае памяти на это не напасешься.